# Get and echo mysql Array from query

Tags: mysql, database, arrays

I'm trying to get an array of id's from my database and then be able to echo out each id.
Something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM TableName WHERE field = 'test' ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo "array: ".$row[1]." <br>";
echo "array: ".$row[2]." <br>";
echo "array: ".$row[3]." <br>";
```

This doesn't seem to be working though?

Comment: Table is a reserved word and must be in backticks. What error do you get?

Comment: Oops, I changed the name - I'm not normally using the name Table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches 1 row. You need to do something like

```
...
$res = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $res[] = $row;
}
//now $res[0] - 1st row, $res[1] - 2nd, etc
```

Comment: Thanks this was indeed the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that mysql_fetch_array fetches an ARRAY, which is 0-based. You're fetching a single field from the database, which will be stored at $row[0] in your result array. Since you're echoing out only row[1] through row[3], you'll never see the result:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
print_r($row);
```

should give you:

```
Array (
    0 => 'id_field_value_here'
)
```

and

```
echo $row[0]
```

would also output

```
id_field_value_here
```